# Is it possible/advisable to have user NOT own home folder?

Tags: linux, permissions

I have previously asked questions about preventing users from deleting certain key files/folders in their home directory by doing something like so:

```
/home
└── [-rw-rw-r-- daedalus    ]  daedalus
    ├── [-rw-rw-r-- root    ]  do_not_delete_file.cpp
    ├── [-rw-rw-r-- root    ]  do_not_delete_file.html
    ├── [-rw-rw-r-- root    ]  do_not_delete_file.php
    ├── [drwxrwxr-x root    ]  do_not_delete_folder
    │   ├── [-rw-rw-r-- root    ]  do_not_delete_file.cpp
    │   ├── [-rw-rw-r-- root    ]  do_not_delete_file.html
    │   └── [-rw-rw-r-- root    ]  do_not_delete_file.php
    └── [-rw-rw-r-- daedalus  ]  index.html
```

But that fails because user `daedalus` has write, and therefore delete, permissions on their own `/home/daedalus` folder. Thus, although they can't modify, for example, `do_not_delete_file.php`, they can always delete it, and later replace it.

but what if instead I had something like this

```
/home
└── [-rw-rw-r-- root    ]  daedalus
    ├── [-rw-rw-r-- root    ]  do_not_delete_file.cpp
    ├── [-rw-rw-r-- root    ]  do_not_delete_file.html
    ├── [-rw-rw-r-- root    ]  do_not_delete_file.php
    ├── [drwxrwxr-x root    ]  do_not_delete_folder
    │   ├── [-rw-rw-r-- root    ]  do_not_delete_file.cpp
    │   ├── [-rw-rw-r-- root    ]  do_not_delete_file.html
    │   └── [-rw-rw-r-- root    ]  do_not_delete_file.php
    ├── [drwxrwxr-x daedalus    ]  Documents
    └── [-rw-rw-r-- root  ]  index.html
```

I'm assuming this is possible with a little `chmod` action, but is it going to lead to many many problems when programs naturally assume they have write permissions to the home directory? If this is a bad idea, could I get some other suggestions as to how to tackle this.

**EDIT:** The reason I ask this question has to do with LAMP programming. I am creating a series of VHosts, ie:

- `www.user1.example.com`
- `www.user2.example.com`
- ...
- `www.userN.example.com`

And I want the DocRoot to be set at:

- `/home/user1`
- `/home/user2`
- ...
- `/home/userN`

However, I am struggling with granting too much/too little freedom to the individual users. In the simplest of cases, I might want a `do_not_delete_folder` which the user can access but can't modify/delete.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here you might try this question on serverfault.com.

Comment: @KenWhite the reason I asked this here is that this ties into LAMP programming, I just didn't go into the detail here. I will edit the question

Comment: @Ken: I think it is on-topic; by analogy, consider the Qmail mailer, which requires two groups and seven user ids for its installation. Understanding the finer points of Unix discretionary access controls is part of what has made it the secure system it is today. Puk is building something similar, for web hosting. Understanding the reasonable options available to him is part of building a quality system.

Comment: @sarnold and puk, fair enough. :) Seems like I've been outnumbered. <g>. Well, not quite yet, but I'll delete my comments so as not to steer others in any direction.

Answer (score 3):

This is a little tricky, but you can do this using the Sticky Bit.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit

The Linux kernel ignores the Sticky Bit except for directories. For directories linux only lets super-users and the owner delete,rename, or unlink files. It does not let a user who has access to the file using the group permission.

For Example, my user is named grape and is a member of the grape group

To Add the Sticky Bit use chmod:

```
chmod +t [file]
```

Here, you can create a Directory that the user has permissions to using groups, but owned by root

> drwxrwxr-T 2 root grape 4096 2012-04-19 20:49 st

In this situation the user can still create/delete his own files in st, but cannot delete root's files, even if the user has write permissions:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root  root  0 2012-04-19 20:45 test 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 grape grape 0 2012-04-19 20:56 test2
```

I can still read/write to both files, but only the files I own I can delete/move

Comment: yes but then would not everyone be able to write to your sticky home folder?

Comment: what do you mean? only members of the group can write to the folder, but in this example I gave my sticky folder 0666 permissions, in the real world 664 or 660 is better.

Comment: @puk: it'd require setting the group owner so only the one user can use it, or use `setfacl(1)` to set access control lists.

Comment: Yes, you will have to create a group for each user and use chown or chgrp or setfacl. But, wont you create a group for each user anyways?

Comment: I see, I was not aware that sticky bits could be fine tuned. I thought it made every folder like `/tmp` where everyone can write to it, but only delete their own files/folders

Answer (score 2):

Many programs -- and users -- expect to be able to create whatever files are necessary directly in their home directory. This might be `~/.xsession-errors`, `~/.viminfo`, `~/.lesshst`, `~/.bash_history`, or others that I might have missed -- or that I don't run, but your users do run.

So, this isn't going to be painless, but here's a few ideas:

- You can come close to what you want by having the home directory owned by someone else *and set the directory's sticky bit* -- this will require the user to own a file or directory before it can be deleted; from `unlink(2)`:

  ```
  EPERM or EACCES
        The directory containing pathname has the sticky bit
        (S_ISVTX) set and the process's effective UID is
        neither the UID of the file to be deleted nor that of
        the directory containing it, and the process is not
        privileged (Linux: does not have the CAP_FOWNER
        capability).
  ```

  You'd either have to go to excessive lengths with either `setfacl(1)` to set access control lists or give every user their own group. Without one of these two steps, you might accidentally grant users permission to modify each other's data.
- You can use the `chattr(1)` attribute `i` to make a file *immutable* -- it cannot be modified, linked, or unlinked, except by a privileged process. From `chattr(1)`:

  ```
  A file with the `i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot
  be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file
  and no data can be written to the file.  Only the superuser
  or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability
  can set or clear this attribute.
  ```
- You can use *bind mounts* to mount the file or directory into the user's home directory. This can be done while the user still owns their home directory; simply run `mount -obind /path/to/source /home/daedalus/do_not_delete`. If the directory or file isn't owned by the user, they cannot modify the file and they cannot modify the mount point itself. (They *can* modify higher-level directories to make the path meaningless -- so do this directly into the home directory but don't try doing it into a subdirectory.)

  ```
  # mount -obind /etc /tmp/sarnold/mount_point/
  # mount -obind /etc/passwd /tmp/sarnold/passwd
  $ rm mount_point/
  rm: cannot remove `mount_point/': Is a directory
  $ rmdir mount_point/
  rmdir: failed to remove `mount_point/': Device or resource busy
  $ mv mount_point/ blob
  mv: cannot move `mount_point/' to `blob': Device or resource busy
  $ rm /tmp/sarnold/passwd 
  rm: remove write-protected regular file `/tmp/sarnold/passwd'? y
  rm: cannot remove `/tmp/sarnold/passwd': Device or resource busy
  $ mv /tmp/sarnold/passwd /tmp/sarnold/old_passwd
  mv: cannot move `/tmp/sarnold/passwd' to `/tmp/sarnold/old_passwd': Device or resource busy
  ```

  (I left out creating the mount points; that's just a simple `touch` or `mkdir`.)

  Of course, the bind mounts go away at every reboot. You may need to use `pam_exec(8)` or configure your `fstab(5)` correctly to re-create the bind mounts at every login or boot.
- You could configure a [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) tool such as [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/) to restrict the privileges available to user processes. (I've been a member of the AppArmor team for twelve years; depending upon how your servers are being used, it may or may not be ideal for this use. I believe most of these systems can be configured to do what you want, but since AppArmor and TOMOYO are *name-based*, I believe they would be more likely to control access to the files and directories than SELinux or SMACK, which are *label-based* systems.)

Comment: Very exhaustive response. Thank you.